# Raise Exception when record not found

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, exception, procedure

I have a table that includes `customer ID` and `order ID` and some other data.

I want to create a `procedure` that takes `customer ID` as input and look inside the table.

if that customer exists then print the `order` details for that customer and 
if customer does not exist  then raise an `exception` "Customer not found."

I have this code, but it's not working properly, or maybe I have the wrong approach to this question.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE order_details(customer NUMBER)
  IS
  CURSOR order_cursor IS
    SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL, CUSTOMER_ID
      FROM PRODUCT_ORDER
  WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = customer ;
  order_row order_cursor%ROWTYPE ;
  customer_error EXCEPTION ;

  BEGIN
        FOR order_row IN order_cursor
    LOOP
      IF order_cursor%FOUND THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('order id = ' || order_row.ORDER_ID) ;
  ELSE
    RAISE customer_error ;
  END IF;
  END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN customer_error THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('no customer' ) ;
      END;
```

So if I run the procedure with this line

```
BEGIN
  order_details(103);
END;
```

I get two results because order exists for this customer.

and if I run the procedure with this line

```
BEGIN
  order_details(101);
END;
```

I don't get anything (not even the error ) because there is no order for that customer.

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJCLG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use an "Explicit Cursor" instead of "Cursor FOR LOOP". Because the latter  just enter the code between LOOP and END LOOP when the query returns more than one record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE order_details(customer NUMBER)
  IS
  CURSOR order_cursor IS
    SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL, CUSTOMER_ID
      FROM PRODUCT_ORDER
  WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = customer ;
  order_row order_cursor%ROWTYPE ;
  customer_error EXCEPTION ;

  BEGIN
  OPEN order_cursor;
  LOOP  
    FETCH order_cursor INTO order_row;
    EXIT WHEN order_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line ('order id = ' || order_row.ORDER_ID);
  END LOOP;

  IF order_cursor%rowcount = 0 THEN
    RAISE customer_error;
  END IF;

  CLOSE order_cursor;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN customer_error THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('no customer' ) ;

END;
```

Regards

Comment: I already tried this too and the problem about this, it is working well when I don't have the customer, but when I have the customer and if that customer have multiple order, it will only shows 1 order for that customer in output and nothing else.

Comment: I upload an image for data inside the table, as you can see I have 2 set of data for example on customer id = 104 but if I use the code you suggest, I would only get one those data and not the other one.

Comment: In this case I have modified the code to use LOOP - END LOOP and attributes %rowcount and %notfound to thereby show all ORDER_ID or 'no customer' if it does not have.